# Android Things Developer Preview 4: flash-all.sh failed on MacOSX

Tags: android-things, intel-edison

I updated the BIOS from Linux following these instructions: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-android-things-on-intel-edison-kit-for-arduino

and then came back to my MacOSX 10.12.5 and tried to run **flash-all.sh**

```
$ uname -a
Darwin ag.intel.com 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ ./flash-all.sh
target reported max download size of 117440512 bytes
sending 'gpt' (33 KB)...
OKAY [  0.008s]
writing 'gpt'...
OKAY [  0.149s]
sending 'u-boot' (375 KB)...
OKAY [  0.020s]
writing 'u-boot'...
OKAY [  0.104s]
erasing 'misc'...
OKAY [  0.132s]
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.415s
ERROR: could not clear input pipe; result e00002ed, ignoring...
ERROR: could not clear output pipe; result e00002d8, ignoring....
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e0004061
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002d9
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002d9
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002d9
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
target didn't report max-download-size
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
FAILED (command write failed (Invalid argument))
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
ERROR: usb_write failed with status e00002c0
error: Device does not support slots.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a regression bug in the **flash-all** script for Edison that will be fixed in the next preview release. You can fix the problem in the interim by making the following modification to `flash-all.sh`:

```
# Due to possible changes in the u-boot version, we might have some
# issues flashing gpt or recognizing the _a/_b partitions.
# Just to be safe, flash and reboot to the updated version
fastboot \
  flash gpt        "${OS}"/partition-table.img \
  flash u-boot     "${VENDOR}"/u-boot-edison.bin \
  erase misc \
  reboot bootloader \
  "$@"
sleep 5  <----- Add this line
```

This will allow the script to continue properly after the initial reboot during the flashing process.